# panic while concat strings

Tags: go, panic

I tried to concatenate a string in the function, but a panic error was reported during the concatenation, and it only happened once. After the process restarted, it was fine.The code I wrote in Go is:

```
646：func (m *LineModule) getKey(timestamp int64, log *model.Log,
647：   loc model.LocationInfo, retMap map[int64]interface{}) {
648：   timeNow := time.Now().Local()
649：   project := util.GetProjectName(log.Flag, log.CustomInfo)
650：   protocol := util.GetProtocol(log, m.IDMap)
651：   version := util.GetVersion(log, m.IDMap)
652：   key := log.Server + log.Level + log.Host + loc.Region + loc.Isp + loc.Country +
653：      strconv.Itoa(log.Tag) + log.ONT + project + "_" + protocol + version   <--- panic here
```

I get the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x55ad1e73b4c1]

goroutine 709 [running]:
data/module.(*LineModule).getKey(0xc001bf4500, 0x55ad1f7d8aa0, 0xc0328ef680, {{0x55ad1edf555e, 0x2}, {0xc0337ad207, 0x6}, {0xc001558ed6, 0x6}}, 0xc001562000)
        /data/module/line_module.go:653 +0x3ec
data/module.(*LineModule).calc(0xc02f250f90, {0x55ad1f2b9478, 0xc0328ef680}, 0x0)
        /data/module/line_module.go:643 +0x247
date/module.(*LineModule).run(0xc001bf4500)
        /data/module/line_module.go:236 +0x126
created by data/module.(*LineModule).Init.func1
        /data/module/line_module.go:180 +0x9b
```

What is going wrong? If the value of `log` in `line 653` is `nil`, the panic occurs. Why does `line 649` not cause the panic? And the panic only happened once.

Comment: Why should line 649 cause panic? It does not even use `loc`.

Comment: My description was incorrect. It is the `log` of line 653, not the `loc`. And `loc` is a structure, not a pointer.

Comment: What exactly is `model.log`? It is an unexported type from another package, how are you using it here?

Comment: One reasonable explanation is that panic is at line 649, not 653.

Comment: I made a mistake when I typed the code. `model.Log` is a structure that stores strings and integers.

Comment: Does panic misreport the number of lines of code?

Comment: Panic will not misreport lines. Based on what you said: if log=nil causes panic, then it should come at the statement at line 649. It is possible that you are not running the code you're seeing.

Comment: But the line number of the call stack can be matched. In the parameters of the `getKey` method, the address of `log` is `0xc0328ef680` instead of `0x0`.

Comment: For that line to panic, one of: log, project, protocol, version  must be nil, which seems unlikely. Another option is what is reported as line 653 by the panic is not what you see in the code (i.e. code is changed since you got this panic). As you observed, none of the args to the function is nil. Another option is one of those strings is corrupt. Is there any `unsafe` use?

Comment: ```func FastBytes2String(b []byte) string {
 return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
}```. To reduce the performance loss caused by the conversion between byets and strings, the strings in `model.Log` are directly converted from `FastBytes2String` function.

Answer (score 0):

log is a pointer to a `model.log` struct. If `log` is `nil`, it is nothing. It does not point to an empty `model.log`-struct. It simply points to nothing. You can't retrieve data from nothing. That's why the error says `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

To get the value of `log.Server`, go tries to find the `model.Log` referenced by the pointer stored in `log`. But `log` points to nothing (`nil`). You can't access nothing. So go panics.

Comment: But why didn't panic when I accessed `log.Flag` on line 649 ?

Comment: What is the type of `log.Server`?

Comment: In `log.Server`, all types except `log.Tag` are string.